Spring Boot @CrossOrigin only in dev
Is there a way in a Spring Boot project to use @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600) for @RestController and @RequestMapping("/api/auth") only within development mode?
The reason for development is that my front-end can be in many different places during development, which is why I need to enable CORS. In production mode this is very different. There I have a focus on security and the front-end has the same origin, which is why I do not want to enable it there.
Is there a way to differentiate this like in this pseudo Java code?
if (mode.dev) {
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
}
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/something")
public class SomeController {
    ...
}


You cannot use conditional on annotations as far as I am aware. But you can create a custom CorsFilter or CorsConfig bean, that can solve your problem
private CorsConfigurationSource createCorsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("mode.dev"))) {
            // Define your CORS configuration for development
            config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        }

        return source;
    }


or,
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("mode.dev"))) {
                    registry.addMapping("/api/something")
                            .allowedOrigins("*")
                            .maxAge(3600);
                }
            }
        };
    }

